# Gratis Windows email client

Tags: windows, gratis, email-client

Thunderbird has just grown too slow for me, and it's time to abandon it.

I am looking for a gratis Windows 10 desktop email client (which is not Thunderbird, or a fork); I do not object if it is cross-platform, so long as it can perform at the speed of a native app.

***MUST HAVE:***

- IMAP support
- able to handle multiple accounts (at least a dozen), and keep them
  separate (I don't object to a combined view, but I want to be able to look at each account seperately)
- good search capabilities (message body too, not just
  header) partial sender address, wildcard searches, date range
  searches, all of these combinable. Preferably search per account and global search across all accounts
- I don't want it scanning my emails & using me as "the product"
- which means no going via a 3rd party server, just straight to my email server by IMAP
- no advertising
- allow me to schedule how    often it checks for new mail
- supports    common mailbox formats, so that I could switch to a new client & import
- and export from this one, if I switch to another client
- can import from Thunderbird
- good spam filtering
- lets me keep all emails locally on hard-drive, so that I can search them even when offline
- can support tens, preferably hundreds, of thousands of emails
- spell checker (you have all seen my atrocious typos often enough on this site; I need a spear chucker^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h^h spell checker)

***NICE TO HAVE:***

- a bunch of plugins would be nice. I especially want GPG support
- let me set the "from address" when sending messages
- tags are nice (and priorities)
- mark as "in need of reply" & remind me
- actively being developed
- good support/forums
- widely used
- any other goodies ;-)

I would prefer a solution that is not from Microsoft, Google, etc, but don't rule them out

Comment: Although you don't describe the problem in much details, maybe there is something you could do to solve the slowness problem in TB. It could be your profile, or certain addons. Try for example to start in safe mode (addons disabled). Perhaps reindex your mailbox files too.

Comment: Agreed, @Anonymous. Also, slowness can be due to the network or email server. I've found Yahoo mail *far* slower than GMail and others, for example.